# extract same values in a list of dictionaries if it present

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I'm trying ti implement a search engine for documents, so i have my index:

```
{'term1': [[document_id1, term_frequency], [document_id2, term_frequency]......]},
{'term2': [[document_id3, term_frequency], [document_id2, term_frequency]......]}
```

and so on...

I should ask for some terms and find all documents that have it(have done this part),
but how can I find ALL the doc_ids that present in my list of dictionaries?

In other words, I need all documents which have ALL the words of the query.
I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
    def match(query):
        match_docs=[]
        for doc in find_doc(query):
            for k,v in doc.items():
                for j in v:
                    if j[0] in i:
                       match_docs.append(j)
        return match_docs
```

For example

```
    terms=[{'rose':[['3',2],['4',4]]},{'trains':[['3',4],['6',5]]}]
```

I need that it returns me '3'

Comment: what is your input and desired output?

Comment: do the dictionaries term1, term2, etc. already exist?

Comment: yes they exist already

Answer (score 0):

Given a document, it is trivial to find if a word is in it:

```
>>> "plump" in open("ulysses.txt", 'r').read()
True
```

The same approach can be taken with a more elaborate query:

```
>>> query = ["Stately", "plump", "Buck", "Mulligan"]
>>> [_ in open("ulysses.txt", 'r').read() for _ in query]
[True, True, True, True]
```

The last hint that I'll give, is that the `all(iterable)` function returns `True` if the iterable is empty, or if `bool(x)` evaluates to `True` for all its values .

```
>>> all([_ in open("ulysses.txt", 'r').read() for _ in query])
True
>>> all([_ in open("dubliners.txt", 'r').read() for _ in query])
False
```

And you should have no problem extending this approach to examine more documents.

Answer (score 0):

Make a set of documents for each query then find the union.  If query is a list of search terms ["term1", "term2", etc] and find_doc returns a list of all documents that match any of the search terms, then you'll want to match on one at a time:

```
def match(query):
    match_docs=[]
    for q in query:
        # generates a list of document IDs for one term at a time
        match_docs.append([doc[0] for doc in find_doc([q])])
    # get the intersection
    # fixed this line in an edit
    s = set(match_docs[0]).intersection(*match_docs)
    return list(s)
```

Comment: This one return  all elements